# How can BDD solve LWE if the matrix A is full rank?

Tags: lattice-crypto

I'm trying to figure out exactly how solving different generic lattice problems can solve LWE, and in particular, BDD. Everything I've found says that since an LWE sample is $(A,b=As+e\mod q$), then the lattice $L_q(A)=\{v : \exists x:Ax=v\mod q\}$ contains $As$, so $b$ is within distance $\Vert e\Vert$ of that lattice. Hence, if a BDD solver can solve for distances up to $\Vert e\Vert $, on input $b$ it should return $As$.

However, if $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix (such as in Frodo), then with high probability $A$ has full rank over $\mathbb{F}_q$. Thus means all vectors in $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ are in the span of $A$, so $L_q(A)=\mathbb{Z}^n$. Then, since $e$ is also an integer vector, $b\in L_q(A)$, so BDD is useless: on input of $b$, it would return $b$.

Can BDD solve LWE here? Is an approximate SVP solver more natural?

Comment: For Frodo and others like it, the coefficient vector $x$ of the lattice point is “short,” so $Ax$ does not cover all of $\mathbb{Z}_q^n$. See the FrodoKEM submission’s modeling of this “normal form” LWE as a BDD problem for a suitable setup of a lattice and nearby BDD vector.

Comment: The FrodoKEM submission explains how BDDwDGS reduces to LWE, then gives attacks based on uSVP, but I can't find an attack based on BDD directly (i.e., a reduction from LWE to BDD). I found a reduction from uSVP to BDD, so one could do LWE=>uSVP=>BDD, but is that all?

Comment: Section 5.2.2 has the reduction LWE<=uSVP. See also Section 5.2.3.

Comment: I saw that and I was chewing through the details (my last comment probably has => backwards). So uSVP can solve normal form LWE fairly directly, but BDD needs to "go through" uSVP first in order to solve LWE?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by “BDD needs to…” LWE is just an average-case BDD problem. Note that Sec 5.2.3 covers an LWE/BDD attack that doesn’t go through uSVP.

Comment: My original question is how to see LWE as an average-case BDD problem, given that the natural lattice to use ($L_q(A)$) contains the LWE sample $b$. Sec 5.2.3 seems to use short lattice vectors directly -- the $(v,w)\in \hat{\Lambda}$. My specific question is: If I have a BDD solver, and a normal form LWE sample $(A,b=As+e)$, what lattice $L$ and what close vector $t$ do I give to the BDD solver?

Comment: Ok. The relevant lattice is the “$q$-ary parity-check lattice” of integer vectors $z$ such that $[A \mid I]z = 0 \pmod{q}$. The target $b = As + e = [A \mid I] (s,e)$ is a “syndrome” that specifies the lattice coset obtained by slightly shifting the lattice, by the short vector $(s,e)$. (This is an equivalent conception of the BDD problem: given a lattice and a coset obtained by a small shift, find that shift.) A good exercise is to write down an explicit basis for this lattice, and to convert $b$ into an explicit BDD target vector in the ambient space of the lattice.

Comment: Oh excellent! That's exactly what I was asking about, thanks.